# get query results from cdbcommand Yii

Tags: php, yii

I've been trying to get the results from my query for the past two hours, in my model I have this

```
public function getQuotes()
        {            
            $data = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('Select fromm from city_fare_final');            
            $data->queryRow();            
            return $data ;
        }
```

in the controller

```
    public function actionIndex()
{
    // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
    // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'
            $model=new QuoteForm();

    if(isset($_POST['QuoteForm']))
    {
                $model->attributes=$_POST['QuoteForm'];

                if ($model->validate())
                {
                    $priceTable=new CityFareFinal;
                    $priceTable->fromm=$model->pickupL;
                    $priceTable->too=$model->dropoffL;                    
                    $priceTable->type_of_car=$model->type;                        
      this->render('result',array('model'=>$priceTable))                        
                }

                }
            else
            {
                $this->render('index',array('model'=>$model));                
            }
}
```

and in the view

```
    <div id="moduleResult">                          
        <span><?php echo $model->getQuotes() ;?><------ Here</span>
    </div>
```

but it always give me an error saying "Object of class CDbCommand could not be converted to string ", what can I do to get the results of my query made in the model???

Regards
Gabriel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public function getQuotes()
        {            
            $data = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('Select fromm from city_fare_final');            
            $data->queryRow();            
            return $data ;
        }
```

Your getQuotes() return `Object of class CDbCommand`:

```
+ You returned $data in the function instead of $data->queryRow().
```

By the way, you cannot use `echo` for `array` data.
The below example is used for fetching data from DB to view by using DAO with Yii: I suppose you have Person model and Person controller

In your Person model:

```
function getData() {
    $sql = "SELECT * from Person";

    $data = Yii::app()->db
        ->createCommand($sql)
        ->queryAll();
    return $data;
}
```

In your controller:

```
function index(){
    $data =  Person::model()->getData();

    $this->render('your_view',array(
    'data'=>$data,
    ));
}
```

In your view: you can `foreach` your data to echo items in the `array` data:

```
<?php foreach($data as $row): ?>
     //show something you want 
     <?php echo $row->name; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

`$data->queryRow();` returns result in array format. Your code is returning `$data` which is an object not result of query. That's why you are getting this error.

If you want to fetch single value you can use $data->queryScalar();

In case of `queryRow()` your code will be

```
public function getQuotes()
    {            
        $data = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('Select * from city_fare_final');            
        $result = $data->queryRow();            
        return $result ; //this will return result in array format (single row)
    }
```

for a single field value you code will be

```
public function getQuotes()
    {            
        $data = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('Select xyz from city_fare_final');            
        $result = $data->queryScalar();            
        return $result; //return single value of xyz column
    }
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

below sample code to traverse rows returned by queryAll

```
$connection = Yii::app()->db;
$command = $connection->createCommand("Select * from table");
$caterow = $command->queryAll(); //executes the SQL statement and returns the all rows

foreach($caterow as $retcat )
{
    echo  $retcat["ColumnName"]  ;
}
```

Returns Arrary of rows with fields

Answer (score 1):

```
 Model: Notices.php:
---------------------------------
public function getNoticesBlog($offset = 0){
    $dataResult =  Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('*')->from($this->tableName())
    ->andWhere("delete_flg=:delete_flg",array(':delete_flg'=>0))
    ->andWhere("publish=:publish",array(':publish'=>1))
    ->limit(3)->offset($offset)->order('created_on DESC')->queryAll();
    return $dataResult;
}
```

Controller: NoticesController.php

```
$firstNotices   = Notices::model()->getNoticesBlog(0);
$secondNotices  = Notices::model()->getNoticesBlog(3);
$thirdNotices   = Notices::model()->getNoticesBlog(6);

$this->render('Notices',array(
        'firstNotices'=>$firstNotices,
        'secondNotices'=>$secondNotices,
        'thirdNotices'=>$thirdNotices,
        )
    );
```